# converting column result to row result in sql

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have query like this:

```
SELECT v.Vtype,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)) AS TotalDiff,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), 
               AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)))) AS Average
FROM   Transaction_tbl t
       LEFT JOIN VType_tbl v
         ON t.vtid = v.vtid
WHERE  t.Locid = 5
GROUP  BY v.Vtype
```

Average
    from Transaction_tbl t left join VType_tbl v on t.vtid=v.vtid where t.Locid =5 group by v.Vtype

My output:

```
Vtype                         TotalDiff   Average
-------------------------------------------------- -
Emaar Staff                     NULL        NULL
Normal                         14044       189.8
VIP                             85          2.1
VVIP                               5           2.5
```

but i want to get out like this:

```
VtypeE      Etotaldiff       Eaverage  VtypeN  Ntot   Naverge  vtypev  vtot  vaverg
Emaar Staff  null             null     Normal   14044    189.8   VIP     85       2.1
```

Comment: Looks like you want to convert rows to columns rather than vice-versa as in the title. That would be an `unpivot`

Comment: for getting that how i can re-write this query

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bring the results all back on one row.  But, the columns have different types.  That means that the built in `pivot` is less practical.  You can do what you want by explicitly aggregating your original query:

```
with cte as (
      SELECT v.Vtype, SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)) AS TotalDiff,
            CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), 
            AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)))) AS Average
      FROM   Transaction_tbl t LEFT JOIN
             VType_tbl v
             ON t.vtid = v.vtid
     WHERE  t.Locid = 5
     GROUP  BY v.Vtype 
   )
select 'Emaar Staff' as VtypeE,
       max(case when type = 'Emaar Staff' then TotalDiff end) as ETotalDiff,
       max(case when type = 'Emaar Staff' then Average end) as EAverage,
       'Normal' as VtypeN,
       max(case when type = 'Normal' then TotalDiff end) as NTotalDiff,
       max(case when type = 'Normal' then Average end) as NAverage,
       'VIP' as VtypeV,
       max(case when type = 'VIP' then TotalDiff end) as VTotalDiff,
       max(case when type = 'VIP' then Average end) as VAverage
from cte;
```